# jQuery hashchange plugin issue

Tags: jquery, plugins, tabs, hashchange

i've an issue with Ben Alman's [hashchange event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) and my custom Tabs_Plugin. Every time the hashchange event was triggered or i've clicked a tab link the page jumps to the top of the page.

Normally i solve those problems simply by adding `return false` or `event.preventDefault` to the links but in this case it is not working for me.

If i add `return false` the whole plugin stops to work. Take a look: http://gearsdigital.com/sandbox/usecase/tabs/

Here is the relevant plugin code. I've included the hashchange plugin above (not included here).

```
// hashchange plugin here

(function ($) {
    var tabs = {
        init : function (element, options) {
            tabs.menu(element, options);
            tabs.navigation(element, options);
            $(window).hashchange();
        },
        // Build tab navigation from headlines
        menu : function (element, options) {
            var menulist = '';
            element.find(options.menusource).each(function () {
                var el = $(this), plaintext = el.text(), parent = el.parent(), itemID = plaintext.split(" ").join("").toLowerCase();
                menulist += '<li><a href="#' + itemID + '">' + plaintext + '</a></li>';
                parent.attr('id', itemID);
            });
            element.prepend('<ul class="' + options.menuclass + '">' + menulist + '</ul>');
            element.find(options.tabbody).wrapAll('<div class="'+options.wrapperclass+'"></div>');
        },
        navigation : function (element, options) {
            $(window).hashchange(function () {
                var menu = $('.' + options.menuclass);
                var hash = location.hash || menu.find('a:first').attr('href');

                if (hash) {
                    menu.find('a').each(function () {
                        var that = $(this);
                        that[that.attr('href') === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](options.currentclass);

                    });
                    tabs.hidetab(element, options);
                    tabs.showtab(element, hash, options.onShow);
                } else {
                    menu.find('a:first').addClass(options.currentclass);
                }    
            });
        },
        showtab : function(element, hash, onShow){
            element.find(hash).show(0, onShow);
        },
        hidetab: function(element, options){
            element.find(options.tabbody).hide();
        }
    };

    $.fn.extend({
        cctabs: function (config, onShow) {
            var defaults = {
                wrapperclass: 'tab-content',
                currentclass: 'current',
                menuclass : 'tabmenu',
                menusource: 'h2',
                tabbody: '.tab',
                onShow: null
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, config);

            return this.each(function () {
                var element = $(this);
                tabs.init(element, options); 
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using Jquery Tools [tabs plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html) with the [history plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/history.html) also from Jquery Tools.

Comment: It's to much overhead for my purposes. I need no Ajax functionality or custom effects. But i need the ability to build the Navigation from the given markup. And i need to learn :)

Comment: So describe me what do you want to do, maybe I can help you with it? I used the hastag plugin using jquery and Ajax so I think if you share your propuse I can help :)

Comment: In case anyone is looking for a similar solution, I created this simple script to manage tabs: http://codepen.io/ivanchaer/post/jquery-tabs